# What javascript library do you recommend to display/popup screenshots on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, screenshot

I've seen some nice screenshot popups around the web, do you know of any library to do that? I could write my own, but... if there's something free I can save time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want a lightbox.

jQuery lightbox gets my vote.

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Dead simple - no point me writing examples, its all there on the site.

Comment: Excellent. I've been using lightview and lightbox (separate apps), and they've both been a bit cryptic to work with. jQuery one as you point out is so simple to use.

Comment: This one does not work on my page - it opens the image way off in the wrong location.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a collection of some Javascript libraries from [Smashing Magazine - 30 Scripts For Galleries, Slideshows and Lightboxes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/) (I excluded CSS-based, see website for full list):

- [JonDesign’s SmoothGallery](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/showcase/gallery/)
- [Pyxy-gallery](http://fennecfoxen.org/pyxy/gallery)
- [zenphoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/)
- [Couloir.org: Resizing, Fading Slideshow Demo - AJAX Slideshow](http://www.couloir.org/js_slideshow/)
- [Grey Box](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/)
- [Lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#example)
- [Litebox](http://www.doknowevil.net/litebox/)
- [Multifaceted Lightbox](http://www.gregphoto.net/lightbox/)
- [Slightly ThickerBox](http://www.jasons-toolbox.com/SlightlyThickerBox/)
- [TripTracker](http://slideshow.triptracker.net/)
- [Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox)
- [Suckerfish HoverLightbox](http://mondaybynoon.com/2006/03/27/suckerfish-hoverlightbox/)
- [Suckerfish HoverLightbox Redux](http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/02/19/suckerfish-hoverlightbox-redux/)
- [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whose website you want thumbnails from, or how many thumbnails.  Look at Alexa's service:

http://aws.amazon.com/ast/

Comment: Serice is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) has two: [Lightbox](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/image/tests/test_Lightbox.html) and [Lightbox Nano](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/image/tests/test_LightboxNano.html) (links are directly to nightlies, this server can be slow).

Answer (score 0):

[Multibox](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Multimedia/Multibox-44125.html) is also quite popular